# JS keypress delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delay action of `.keypress()` method in jQuery for a certain amount of seconds.

I looked for the solution like:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

and `setInterval`,`setTimeout` methods as well but in the first variant it freezes the entiry page what I really don't want to do. and in the second I don't know how to wrap my script into these functions.

My code sample :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//some code
    $(document).keypress(function(event){/*...this fragment I want to be freezed*/});
});
```

## Question explanation:

Let's say that I have a simple counter which is in `keypress` event handler counts how many times *Enter* button is pressed by user. And after the third click I want page not to response on user presses for 5 seconds without freezing the whole page(user still can click on a certain `<button>` etc.. but any pressing on keyboard will do nothing untill 5 secs left(freeze `keypress` event handler).

Comment: Your first code snippet is a busy loop -- it will peg one core to 100% while it's waiting for the delay to elapse. You should never do that. Look around for event *throttling* for answers to your main question.

Comment: Im not sure if this will work, but try this: `$(document).delay(5000).keypress(function(){};);`

Comment: @Manu It won't work.

Comment: @Juhana setInterval doesn't work in my case... Unexplained downvoting.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why setTimeout wouldn't work (you don't want setInterval because, well, you don't want an interval.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I know about busy loop and its dangerous. That's why I'm asking about another way to freez.

Comment: @Juhana I didn't mention that I don't want it. Just suggest your way of using it instead of downvoting.

Comment: And you don't want it because...? (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: I want to use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` in any possible way but I can't figure out how to use it. That's why I'm asking here. Please read my question explanation above.

Comment: @Vad, *why* would you want to use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` *without being able to figure out how to use [them]*? Have you read the documentation about timeout ids and how you revoke them?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I wrote code. I tried to do it myself. I googled for good answers and practices and read documentation. After all I've come here for explanation from experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something rather simple

```
var delay = ( function () {
    var ticker = null;

    return function( callback, ms ) {
        if ( ticker !== null ) {
            clearTimeout( ticker )
        }

        ticker = setTimeout(callback, ms)
    }
} () )

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Pass delay two parameters, the first one is the callback
    // You want to delay, the second is the time in milliseconds to wait
    $(document).on( "click", function() {
         delay( function(){ ... }, 3000 )
    } );
});
```

Here's an example of how to use this: http://jsfiddle.net/p0tf8of0/8/

Here is another variation of the delay function, this one accepts a third parameter used for delaying after a certain amount of invocations.

```
var delay = ( function () {
    var ticker = null;
    var invokedCounter = 0

    return function( callback, ms, delayAfter ) {
        if ( typeof delayAfter === "number" && delayAfter > 0 && delayAfter === invokedCounter ) {
            if ( ticker !== null ) {
                clearTimeout( ticker )
            }

            ticker = setTimeout(callback, ms)
        } else {
            invokedCounter++
            callback()
        }
    }
} () )
```

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/p0tf8of0/12/

Comment: can I pass my `keypress` handler there somehow?

Comment: of course you can, that's the all idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can I delay my callback only when user has clicked *without* delay for 4 times already?

Comment: Let me get this right, you want to apply the delay logic only when the something was already clicked 4 times ?

Comment: in your example it apears without any click at all in Google Chrome. Did I miss something?

Comment: I want to apply the delay logic after a *certain goal reached* in this case yes, after it was 4 times clicked already

Comment: @VadZelenin The broken examples ( both here & jsfiddle ) have been amended. The issue was due to the event "keypress" and incorrect usage of the delay

Comment: @VadZelenin I have updated my answer to address your "4 times" threshold.

Comment: It is really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use [debounce()](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) function from lodash or underscore (a utility js library)

Debounce allow to trigger event only one time in the period defined.

jQuery('#myDiv').on('click', _.debounce(myFunction, 300, { 'leading': true, 'trailing': false }));

Comment: Please elaborate on how to use this.

Comment: Debounce allow to trigger event only one time in the period defined. `jQuery('#myDiv').on('click', _.debounce(myFunction, 300, {
  'leading': true,
  'trailing': false
}));`

Comment: *(Downvotes are not mine but hint: your last comment should be part of your answer, possibly with more plain-text information about what `debounce()` actually does.*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks for the hint